# How to sort list in parallelStream?

Tags: java, list, sorting, parallelstream

Is there a way to sort a list using `parallelStream()`? I saw there are `forEach` and `forEachOrdered`. But I was checking if there is a way to sort as follows,

```
list.parallelStream().map().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What doesn't work with your above snippet? FYI, `.sorted()` is [_stateful_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps): "one cannot produce any results from sorting a stream until one has seen all elements of the stream".

Comment: What help do you need?  That works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parallel stream is just a standard stream, so it is possible to apply `sorted` to a parallel stream. The result of the `sorted` method is a sequential stream.

So it works as follow:

```
 list.parallelStream()   // Generate a parallel stream
     .map(item -> ...)   // Item are mapped in parallel
     .sorted()           // sorted needs to wait for all elements before continuing
                         // Here the stream is sequential
     .collect(Collectors.toList());   // Collect to a new list
```

So **sorted can operates on a parallel stream**, but the **resulting stream is sequential** and it is released **only after all elements of the parallel stream are received**.

---

Updated answer (thanks to @Louis Wasserman)

The result of sorted is not sequential. The terminal operation will maintain the same order of the original stream not depending on if it is a sequential stream or a parallel stream.
So the correct code exposed before must be changed in the comments as below

```
 list.parallelStream()   // Generate a parallel stream
     .map(item -> ...)   // Item are mapped in parallel
     .sorted()           // sorted needs to wait for all elements before continuing
                         // REMOVED --> Here the stream is sequential
     .collect(Collectors.toList());   // Collect to a new list
                                      // ADDED --> in the same order of the received after the sorted step
```

If you add a map operation after the sorted with a random executing time you can see that this map operation can end in different moments, but at the end the collect will generate a List in the original order. (thanks to Louis Wasserman... I did a mistake I was not knowing the real internal details of stream, I hope that the updated answer give you the ability to better understand how streams works)

Comment: Why do you believe the stream is sequential?  Parallel doesn't mean unordered.

Comment: I edit the answer to show you with a basic example

Comment: The result of `.sorted()` _isn't_ sequential, though.  It does wait until the sort is complete, but further operations on it will be executed in parallel.

Comment: Thank you @LouisWasserman ... I had a bad idea on how stream internally worked. Your comments opened my mind. Is there any "official" documentation explaining it?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. And also thank you for putting your time to answer this question.